# Computing Adjusted Rand Index

Tags: python, debugging, k-means

I am trying to compute the [ARI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rand_index#Adjusted_Rand_index) between two sets of clusters, using this code:

```
#computes ARI for this type of clustering
def ARI(table,n):

index = 0
sum_a = 0
sum_b = 0
for i in range(len(table)-1):
    for j in range(len(table)-1):
        sum_a += choose(table[i][len(table)-1],2)
        sum_b += choose(table[len(table)-1][j],2)
        index += choose(table[i][j],2)


expected_index = (sum_a*sum_b)
expected_index = expected_index/choose(n,2)
max_index = (sum_a+sum_b)
max_index = max_index/2

return (index - expected_index)/(max_index-expected_index)


#choose to compute rand
def choose(n,r):

f = math.factorial
if (n-r)>=0:
    return f(n) // f(r) // f(n-r)
else:
    return 0
```

assuming I have created the contingency table correctly, I still get values outside the range of (-1,1).

For instance:

Contingency table:

```
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2]
[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 3]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]
[3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0]
```

yields an ARI of `-1.6470588235294115` when I run my code.
Is there a bug in this code?

Also Here is how I am computing the contingency matrix:

```
table = [[0 for _ in range(len(subjects)+1)]for _ in range(len(subjects)+1)]
#comparing all clusters
for i in range(len(clusters)):
    index_count = 0
    for subject, orgininsts in orig_clusters.items():
        madeinsts = clusters[i].instances
        intersect_count = 0
        #comparing all instances between the 2 clusters
        for orginst in orgininsts:
            for madeinst in makeinsts:
                if orginst == madeinst:
                    intersect_count += 1

        table[index_count][i] = intersect_count
        index_count += 1


for i in range(len(table)-1):
    a = 0
    b = 0
    for j in range(len(table)-1):
        a += table[i][j]
        b += table[j][i]

    table[i][len(table)-1] = a
    table[len(table)-1][i] = b
```

`clusters` is a list of cluster objects that have attribute `instances`, which is a list of instances contained in that cluster. `orig_clusters` is a dictonary with keys representing cluster labels, and values are a list of instances contained in that cluster. Is there a bug in this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You make some mistakes calculating the ARI in your code -- you calculate a and b too often because you loop over your table twice instead of just once.

Also, you pass n as a parameter, but apparently it is set to 10 (that is how I get your result). It would be easier to just pass the table and then calculate n from there. I fixed your code a bit:

```
def ARI(table):
    index = 0
    sum_a = 0
    sum_b = 0
    n = sum([sum(subrow) for subrow in table]) #all items summed

    for i in range(len(table)):
        b_row = 0#this is to hold the col sums
        for j in range(len(table)):
            index += choose(table[i][j], 2)
            b_row += table[j][i]
        #outside of j-loop b.c. we want to use a=rowsums, b=colsums
        sum_a += choose(sum(table[i]), 2)
        sum_b += choose(b_row, 2)

    expected_index = (sum_a*sum_b)
    expected_index = expected_index/choose(n,2)
    max_index = (sum_a+sum_b)
    max_index = max_index/2

    return (index - expected_index)/(max_index-expected_index)
```

or if you pass on the table with row- and column sums:

```
def ARI(table):

    index = 0
    sum_a = 0
    sum_b = 0
    n = sum(table[len(table)-1]) + sum([table[i][len(table)-1] for i in range(len(table)-1)])
    for i in range(len(table)-1):
        sum_a += choose(table[i][len(table)-1],2)
        sum_b += choose(table[len(table)-1][i],2)
        for j in range(len(table)-1):
            index += choose(table[i][j],2)

    expected_index = (sum_a*sum_b)
    expected_index = expected_index/choose(n,2)
    max_index = (sum_a+sum_b)
    max_index = max_index/2

    return (index - expected_index)/(max_index-expected_index)
```

then

```
def choose(n,r):
    f = math.factorial
    if (n-r)>=0:
        return f(n) // f(r) // f(n-r)
    else:
        return 0

table = [[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2],
[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 3],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
[3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0]]

ARI(table)

ARI(table)
Out[56]: -0.0604008667388949
```

The correct result!

Comment: Thank you, just for completeness, the last row and column of `table` are the sums of the each of the rest of their row, and column, so what I really wanted to do is calculate the ARI on `table[len(table)-1][len(table)-1]`, and use the two last columns to calculate `sum_a` and `sum_b`, although deleting the last column and row, and then running your version of `ARI(table)` works, and there is no need to create the last row and column.

Comment: Oh - I didn't see that. In that case, you loop one too many times for a and b, please see my edit :)